# Web app returning data but too slow

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, html, web-services, jquery

I have created data driven web app that uses MVC 4.0, WebServices, RestFul, SQLServer 2008 R2, jQuery Mobile (one page app), AJAX architecture.

When a user clicks 'Search by name' > 'Browse names' this brings in all the data from a table users (and a couple of other data lookup tables).

The app has been designed to be used on Retina displays as well as normal ones (one large size image only) and re-sizes them in the html.

The problem is this search can take sometimes 10 secs to return around 400 records but by using the URI it takes only around two. Is this normal, and can [lazy loading](http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/lazyload) help? How could I implement this in the AJAX below?

AJAX:

```
function getConsultants() {

    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        async: false,
        url: 'http://31.222.187.42/hca-consulting/Farm/users',
        //url: 'json/get_consultants.txt',
        dataType: 'json',

        success: function (users) {

           hcaConsultants = users;

        },
    });
};
```

Comment: Please see above for the AJAX call

Comment: yes its almost normal. As sometimes the API you are using might be slow. And you need to upgrade it! Or you need some code that would help boast up your code.

Comment: @AfzaalAhmadZeeshan I would say this is far from normal or expected behaviour and there are specific reasons for it. Apps, particularly mobile focused apps need to be optimized heavily, see my answer for details.

Comment: Thats true! You might consider visiting https://developers.google.com/speed/ They will teach you basics for this! If you use WebMatrix for this work. YOu can use Reports Tab to check which pages take too long to execute and why!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what I believe your issues are:

1. Initial page load amounts to 13.1MB (easy, tiger!). Obviously this needs to be addressed. Run all of your PNGs and JPEGs through an optimizer. [Here](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/a56eddd3-d79b-48ac-8c8f-2db06ade77c3) is one that is an add on for Visual Studio. In light of this, on many PCs, the RAM use of the browser process will hit the roof. Chrome hit 250MB for me and Opera 650MB usage. It's a heavy, heavy page with 171 requests on initial page load. That is really high. Consider using sprites for your images as well, consolidate as many as you can, the performance difference is stunning; the higher the number of requests the less efficient a page becomes.
2. Do you really need to preload *all* those images? Definitely consider the lazy loader you mention or other image loader as appropriate.
3. When the browse names is invoked, the number of requests goes up to 548 individual items on the HTTP stack, going up to 14.3MB (but all of the image links are broken, so I would suggest, once you get those in place, it would be 30+MB at that point. That is obviously unacceptable for potentially a mobile (web or install?) application.
4. You may wish to consider also thinking about jQuery templating for speed of delivery of those records to the DOM. In addition, you could also implement a scroll load like the [waypoint plugin](http://imakewebthings.com/jquery-waypoints/) which is a beautifully minimized 8kb, so more JSON results appear in the browser as they scroll down; the fewer records you are dealing with at any one time increases your in-browser efficiency and responsiveness.
5. You will need *heavy*, *heavy* caching here if you are delivering this over the web rather than as an installed app, embrace it with open arms. Also consider bundling and minifying all of your own Javascript into one file at build time with a VS post build event and my hero, Douglas Crockford's [JSMin](http://www.crockford.com/javascript/jsmin.html) or by using the bundling built into the framework. Also, CDNs for your libraries.

Really that is it, the reason your page is loading so slowly is that it's groaning under the weight of its resources, hence why your api's JSON comes back so quickly when requested directly.

[This](http://www.gtmetrix.com/) is a great website for comparing your page speed and Yslow scores and here is the [report with recommendations for your site](http://www.2shared.com/document/Je6pwuXe/GTmetrix-report-3122218742-201.html) for additional tips and tricks. Responsiveness and perceived speed is everything for these kinds of apps, so I am rooting for you to make it world class.

I hope this helps and good luck with your app.

Comment: Moby's Stunt Double thanks for that list! The Lazy Load plugin mentions images that are loaded laziliy could I apply this to the divs that are beig loaded?